Error in summary(model_component)$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
there is a   model.results list which has  multiple elements and sub elements in it.
Here using this list trying to extract certain values and convert into  proper format for storing purpose.
Below is the sample code
for id in abc{
    model.results <- "  after function executes successfully  here generates results and stores 
                          in the model.results"

    model.results.table <-   model.results.table <- data.table(rbindlist(lapply(model.results, 
    format.model.for.output), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE))
   model.results.table$NOTES =paste0('with abcthreshold $')
    N.Pars <- sqldf('select count(*) as "No.Pars", "id" ,"qual"
                          from "model.results.table" group by  "id","qual"')
  model.results.table <- merge(x=model.results.table, y=N.Pars, by=c( "id","qual"))
  
  
  
  model.results.all[[id]] <- model.results.table
}

FUNCTIONS:
format.model.for.output <- function(model.info.list)
{
  model.info.table.primary <- extract.info.from.model.ols(model.info.list, "rq")
  model.info.table.secondary <- extract.info.from.model.ols(model.info.list, "sim", include.original.params = FALSE)
  model.info.table.tertiary <- extract.info.from.model.ols(model.info.list, "sim.db", include.original.params = FALSE)

  model.info.all <- bind_rows(model.info.table.primary, model.info.table.secondary, model.info.table.tertiary)
  
  return(model.info.all)
}


extract.info.from.model.ols <- function(model.info.list, model.info.index, include.original.params = TRUE){
  model.info <- model.info.list[[model.info.index]]
  print('model.info')
  Par= data.frame(covar  = as.vector(rownames(data.frame(model.info$coefficients))), 
                  Weight = as.vector(data.frame(model.info$coefficients))[,1],
                  Pvalue =as.vector(summary(model.info)$coefficients[,4]),
                  orgcovar =as.vector(model.info$subset.ORG.IND.OLS),
                  transformation =as.vector(model.info$subset.TRANSFORMATION))
  if(include.original.params){
    Par.NNLS= data.frame(covar  = as.vector(rownames(data.frame(model.info.list$nnlspars))), 
                         Weight = as.vector(data.frame(model.info.list$nnlspars))[,1],
                         Pvalue = NA,
                         orgcovar =as.vector(model.info.list$org.ind.vars),
                         transformation =as.vector(model.info.list$model.trans)) 
    Par.NNLS <- subset(Par.NNLS, Weight ==0)
    Par <- rbind(Par,Par.NNLS)
  }

  Par$adj.r.squared = summary(model.info)$adj.r.squared
  
  Par$covar = as.character(Par$covar) 
  Par$ID_MS= model.info$id
  ....
  .....
  Par2 <- merge(x=Par, y=getorgparfile, by=c("id", "orgcovar"), all.x=T)
  return(Par2)
}

while executing the above code receiving multiple error like $ i snot atomic vector or doesnt ave summary object .
Execute dthe above code with multiple changes and also executed manually outside the function putting model.results explicitly and it worked.But the same using in teh function an din the loop throwing the above errors
example: below code used to execute outside the function and it worked.
model.info.list <- model.results  
model.info.index <- model.info.list[["rq"]] 
model.info <- model.info.index

str(model.info)

summary_info <- summary(model.info)
str(summary_info)

Par= data.frame(covar = names(model.info$coefficients), 
                Weight = model.info$coefficients ,
                Pvalue = summary(model.info)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"],
                orgcovar = model.info$subset.ORG.IND.OLS,
                transformation = model.info$subset.TRANSFORMATION) 

If executing in the loop and in the function ,  the model.info.index is  having null hence none of the other lines getting executed.
example:model.results output will be something like below in R studio:
model.results
Name                 list               value
rq                  list26    list of length 26
coefficients     double[3]            24,25,26
a             24                    24
b             25                    25
c             26                    26
res             double[20]            -20,35,-78,etc
...(etc)
sim              list26    list of length 26
...(etc)
sim.db
...(etc)
expected output: in a table format

